# Android - Same content in multiple tabs

Tags: java, android

My application consists of a tab layout with six tabs. Each tab represents a player in a game.

I would like the activities within each tab to contain the exact same XML layout and code as the activities in the other tabs. Each player will get access to the same widgets and input fields.

Is there a way to write one activity and have each tab use that activity as a template? I am trying to avoid copying the code for the six activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create a parent activity to [setcontentview(int resourceId,)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29). That way you can write all the shared code inside the parent and just set all of your activities to extend your parent.

Parent Class:

```
    public class ParentActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.sharedLayoutFile);
            }
    }
```

All Other Activities

```
    public class AllActivities extends ParentActivity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                    ...and more code for other stuff like linking data to UI, which
                    could be done in the parent if it is a standard data format.
            }
    }
```

Comment: The key thing to know is that `super.onCreate(...` runs the code in `ParentActivity`'s `onCreate`, without the need to copy it over manually.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about doing this and it looks like it works! Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I am not a java expert or an andorid expert but I would make a master activity and all the sub activites use a referance or a pointer to look at the main activy there for u will have a total of 7 but 6 of them will assable there data based on the pointer of the first one so if the first one changes the others ones change also.